# Можно ли test_case размещать в циклах?

Tags: c++, catch2

Собственно, есть ли ограничения на размещение `TEST_CASE`, `WHEN`, `THEN` и др. в циклах?

Comment: @Abyx а что по поводу остальных?

Comment: кто-нибудь может объяснить за что минусы?

Comment: А что мешает проверить?

Comment: @Abyx, можно и не такое надефайнить))

Comment: @Qwertiy дело в том, что обычно в одно из тестов у меня имеется цикл в котором находится много вложенных `when` `then` и он на второй итерации стабильно валится с ошибкой прямиком из Catch2. Но в других местах, где так же есть циклы со вложенными `when` `then` все работает ок. Поэтому и спрашиваю допустимо ли это.